# sass not found: How to setup Tailwind in Nuxt with vite

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vite

### Scenario

I just install vite, because my nuxt app got extremely slow. Like 10-30 seconds for hot module replacement.

But now, the sass in my components for tailwind does not work anymore.

### Error

```
[plugin:vite:css] Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?
```

Altough, if I remove the vite message in the browser per click:

```
require is not defined
```

But a sass-loader is installed?!

### Steps to fix

- reinstalled tailwind and installed
- reinstalled sass-loader
- installed pug pug-plain-loader
- installed sass sass-loader@10 fibers

Answer (score 10):

Try running

`yarn add --dev sass sass-loader@latest`

Something similar happened to me

Comment: For NPM, simply use `npm add --dev sass sass-loader@latest`